# Load more cells "willDisplayCell" Problem

Tags: iphone, xml, uitableview, load

i have a problem with willDisplayCell it doesn't stop fetch Xml from the url
my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [itemsToDisplay count] + 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


if (indexPath.row == [itemsToDisplay count]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Load More...";


} else {
    MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = item.title;
}

    return cell;
}




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      if (indexPath.row == [itemsToDisplay count]) {

    // Parse
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/RayWilliamJohnson/uploads?v=2&alt=rss&sort_field=added&start-index=21&max-results=20"];
    feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
    feedParser.delegate = self;
    feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull; // Parse feed info and all items
    feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
    [feedParser parse];



    [self.tableView reloadData];
}    
}
```

its look like he is in kind of loop that doesnt stop fetch xml

so how can i fix it so i will only called once?

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have called *reloadData* within *tableView:willDisplayCell:*. *reloadData* will cause every UITableViewCell to get drawn again, means willDisplayCell will get called for every cell that will be visible on screen. Seems to me like you have an infinite loop there.

*tableView:willDisplayCell:* is definitely the wrong place to be doing that XML parsing. willDisplayCell should just be used to prepare the UI. I can't say for certain, but perhaps a better place to the XML parsing would be in your view controller's *init* method.